# Java - mkdir() creates read-only directory

Tags: java, mkdir

I am creating a directory ("FileAdmin") with the following code:

```
public class FileAdmin {

    private File dir;

    public FileAdmin() throws IOException{
        this.dir = new File("FileAdmin");
        if(!dir.exists() & !dir.mkdir()) throw new IOException();
}
```

Main does the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        FileAdmin fa = new FileAdmin();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is not a problem; when I create a file inside the directory  (which succeeds) and try to delete it, I can't. The problem is that mkdir() creates a read-only directory, no matter what I do:

[image: FileAdmin properties on Windows 10 / "Solo lectura" = read-only]

*Solo lectura -> read-only*

I have already tried `dir.setWritable(true);` but it always returns `false`. Why is this?

**EDIT 1:** If I create the dir, uncheck the `read-only` option in the folder's properties, once i run the code file is deleted

**EDIT 2:** I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Why are you using a bitwise or here `!dir.exists() & !dir.mkdir()`? This will always attempt to make the directory, even if it already exists. Use the logical or `&&` which will shortcut and not evaluate the second half of the expression if the first half is already true.

Comment: Aside: don't do work like that in a constructor. Constructors should only initialize the object; add a separate method to create the directory.

Comment: create the folder manually, in the same location, and check his properties. I assume it would be the same.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am doing this because the object is a directory, suited for a specific project. Its purpose is on the methods that I'm not showing because they're irrelevant to the problem

Comment: BTW the black square in read only doesn't mean it is read-only , it is in an unknown state. You can click on that box and change it to ticked or non-ticked state.

Comment: Also it will be helpful if you can post the stacktrace or error when you say : `when I create a file inside the directory (which succeeds) and try to delete it, I can't. `

Comment: @svasa it doesn't throw an exception, it simply returns `false`

Comment: If this is windows 10, are you trying to create the folder in a protected location (e.g. Program Files), by default those locations are read only.

Comment: @Micheal - those are not a "bitwise" operators.  Java "bitwise" operators are defined for integral types, but not for `boolean`.  In that context, `&` is a non-short-circuit logical operator.  (Lets get the terminology right when we instruct people ... )

Comment: @Goibniu yes, I am using Windows 10. What's the solution to this? Should I create the dir in a specific location outside my project?

Comment: Windows doesn't have read-only directories, only read-only files. That checkbox is for setting/unsetting the read-only flag on all the files in the folder. Also, `File.delete` will delete read-only files anyway, so that isn't the problem. Are you sure you have the right file path? Try doing a `File.exists` check before the delete instruction.

Comment: Yes, I am using the exact same path for creation and deletion.

Comment: Try calling `java.nio.file.Files.delete(yourFile.toPath())` and see what exception it throws, it could be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your problem correctly or not but
i tried the following code, where a folder **FileAdmin** is created and inside the folder a file named **WritableFile.txt** is created and lastly the file has been deleted.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File directory = new File("FileAdmin");
        directory.mkdir();
        File file = new File("FileAdmin/WritableFile.txt");
        file.createNewFile();

        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Please correct me if i understood your question differently. I am on windows 10. If you will comment the file.delete() then you will see the file inside the folder.

Comment: Tried my code on Linux, and it works. I believe it has something to do with permissions, thanks for your help